# How to identify different values in duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sqldf

Considering that i have the following table:

[image]

How i make a query that identify if the same **code** ( there can be duplicates, no problem with that at all ) have a diferent **sex**?

Example:

```
Code   Sex
1900   Male
1900   Female
```

I tried to do a little reseach before questioning here, but couldn't find the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select code
from t
group by code
having min(sex) <> max(sex);
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want is:

```
Select code, 
count(distinct sex) as val 
from table 
group by code 
having val>1
```